# Partition USB to raw partition

Tags: partition, system-installation, live-usb, manjaro

I'm now running Window 7 and I want to install Manjaro Linux on the other disk on my computer.

In the [installation guide](http://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Burn_an_ISO_File), the author said:

```
 Should your attempt to write to a USB stick still be unsuccessful, 
 then use a partition tool to format it as a RAW partition type, 
 use ImageWriter again.
```

So my question is: How can I format my USB from FAT32 to raw and which software should I use?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from Windows? If so you can bring up the disk manager, `compmgmt.msc`, and select "Disk Management". From there you can delete the partitions on the USB drive.

Comment: @slm: Yes, I want to this from Window 7, since I have nothing to do without it.

Comment: You could download a live CD/DVD of Linux and do the re-partitioning/formatting from that too. GParted Live can do this: http://gparted.org/livecd.php. Details for some of what to do from Windows are here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309000.

Comment: @slm : Thank you. Is raw a partition that is not formatted, i.e, I just have to open the Computer management, delete the usb partition, then open the Image Writer and write the image?

Comment: I believe that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format it as ext3 or 4, so according to the guide, in command line you just have to run:

```
dd bs=4M if=/path/to/manjaro.iso of=/dev/sd[drive letter]
```

Which [drive letter] is your Hard Drive detected in /dev, For Example a, b or c...

And for formatting your flash maybe need some live Linux like Ubuntu. If you'll use Live Ubuntu, it have tool named gParted which can do many things for you on your disks and partitions, Or else run

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1
```

For formating your partitions by CLI.